# Is it possible to control Firefox's DNS requests in an addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I was wondering if it was possible to intercept and control/redirect DNS requests made by Firefox?
The intention is to set an independent DNS server in Firefox (not the system's DNS server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. The DNS resolver is made available via the `nsIDNSService` interface. That interface is not fully scriptable, so you cannot just replace the built-in implementation with your own Javascript implementation.

But could you perhaps just override the DNS server?

The built-in implementation goes from `nsDNSService` to `nsHostResolver` to `PR_GetAddrByName` (nspr) and ends up in `getaddrinfo`/`gethostbyname`. And that uses whatever the the system (or the library implementing it) has configured.

Any other alternatives?

Not really. You could install a proxy and let it resolve domain names (requires some kind of proxy server of course). But that is a very much a hack and nothing I'd recommend (and what if the user already has a real, non-resolving proxy configured; would need to handle that as well).

Comment: Good... I will read about those and see if I can make it into a working addon (later). FoxyProxy has the ability/option to pass the DNS request through its proxy. So I thought it should be possible. It helps people who dont have access to system DNS config.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the "problem loading page" and then probably use [*`redirectTo`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel#redirectTo%28%29) method on it.

Basically they all load `about:neterror` url with a bunch of info after it. IE:

- `about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//www.cu.reporterror%28%27afew/&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20can%27t%20find%20the%20server%20at%20www.cu.reporterror%28%27afew.`
- `about:neterror?e=malformedURI&u=about%3Abalk&c=&d=The%20URL%20is%20not%20valid%20and%20cannot%`

But this info is held in the docuri. So you have to do that. Here's example code that will detect problem loading pages:

```
var listenToPageLoad_IfProblemLoadingPage = function(event) {

    var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;
    var docuri = window.gBrowser.webNavigation.document.documentURI; //this is bad practice, it returns the documentUri of the currently focused tab, need to make it get the linkedBrowser for the tab by going through the event. so use like event.originalTarget.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.document.documentURI <<i didnt test this linkedBrowser theory but its gotta be something like that
    var location = win.location + ''; //I add a " + ''" at the end so it makes it a string so we can use string functions like location.indexOf etc

    if (win.frameElement) {
      // Frame within a tab was loaded. win should be the top window of
      // the frameset. If you don't want do anything when frames/iframes
      // are loaded in this web page, uncomment the following line:
      // return;
      // Find the root document:
      //win = win.top;
      if (docuri.indexOf('about:neterror') == 0) {
          Components.utils.reportError('IN FRAME - PROBLEM LOADING PAGE LOADED docuri = "' + docuri + '"');
      }
    } else {
        if (docuri.indexOf('about:neterror') == 0) {
            Components.utils.reportError('IN TAB - PROBLEM LOADING PAGE LOADED docuri = "' + docuri + '"');
        }
    }
}


window.gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listenToPageLoad_IfProblemLoadingPage, true);
```

Comment: Thanks Noitidart... but it has to be done before window. DNS queries are the first step, then there is the header query/exchange and then HTTP and then browser makes a window, parses DOM, and 'DOMContentLoaded'. I need to grab it **before** the DNS query. I found out that there is method for rerouting DNS through proxy but I dont want to use a proxy.